# Is there any isomorphism between these two groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there any isomorphism between these two groups?

$(\mathbb{Q}^*,\cdot)$ and $(\mathbb{Z}_2,+)\times (\mathbb{Z}[x],+)$.

Comment: Could you please clarify what the second group is defined as? What does the $^*$ denote?

Comment: It is direct product and the former one refers to Q without zero.

Comment: Please use Mark-up, not boldface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint.** A nonzero rational number can be written as
$$(-1)^k\prod_{i=1}^{\infty}p_i^{a_i}$$
where $p_1,p_2,\ldots$ are the distinct positive primes, and the $a_i$ are nonnegative integers, all but finitely many equal to $0$. The expression *almost* unique, two expressions only differing possibly in the value of $k$, but respecting its parity.

How is multiplication reflected in this way of expressing rationals?